# Change UIButton Color With Defined Color

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, title, uicolor

I want to change my title color with an already defined color. Here's my code.

```
#define GHOSTWHITE_COLOR    ([UIColor colorWithRed:248/255.0 green:248/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1]);

[loginBtn setTitleColor:GHOSTWHITE_COLOR forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

But I'm having this error:

> Expression result unused** or  **Expected ']'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the semicolon at the end of the `#define`. Get rid of the semicolon there. Then of course you need to add a semicolon to your regular method call.

```
#define GHOSTWHITE_COLOR  ([UIColor colorWithRed:248/255.0 green:248/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1])

[loginBtn setTitleColor:GHOSTWHITE_COLOR forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

---

A better solution is to create a category on UIColor and add a class property for your custom color. Then you can use your custom color just like any other.h

UIColor+Custom.h:

```
@interface UIColor (Custom)

@property (nonatomic, readonly, class) UIColor *ghostWhiteColor;

@end
```

UIColor+Custom.m:

```
@implementation UIColor (Custom)

+ (UIColor *)ghostWhiteColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:248/255.0 green:248/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1];
}

@end
```

Now you can use this like any other color:

```
[loginBtn setTitleColor:UIColor.ghostWhiteColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```